# Reference and store Data from Dynamically created Controls?

Tags: c#, sqlite, dynamic, user-controls

I have a problem I've been looking into for a few days now, I just can't think of a logical way of doing what I want.

I have an app which has a task list. It starts of with 3 controls: a textbox, datetimepicker and a PictureBox which changes image on click. The user can then press an image which will add another row of controls below (It gets the properties of the dynamic controls from the controls already created):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/o2pub6orww24w25/tasklist.png (This is a screenshot to make it clearer)

Now what I want to do is save the values from each of the rows (A row being defined as: Textbox, Date, Status) into an SQLite DB.

For the first row it is easy, because that has a unique design name (and is a 'static' control).
However, the problem hits when I attempt to save values from the dynamic controls:

**Problem a)** I cannot reference the dynamic control because 'It does not Exist in the current Context'. -The function for creating the controls has a public access modifier so I thought that should do the trick? -It didn't. I've also tried:`Panel1.pb.blah` but it still didn't recognize the control?

**Problem b)** How can I tell my program that each row is a new set of data? In other words, how can I run a new insert command for each row? -I thought of doing this as a for-each-textbox loop, however would that not just pick up the first dynamic date everytime?

I've also thought of using the tag property and setting it to the counter variable, to group the controls in the row. (The counter being an integer which increments every time a new row is added.) However I cannot do that because the picture box uses the tag property as part of its function to change image on click (Changes multiple times).

Code:

Adding the Controls:

```
public void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //TextBox Control
        int tbh = tasktb.Location.Y + (counter*25);
        int tbsh = tasktb.Size.Height;
        int tbsw = tasktb.Size.Width;
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Location = new Point(9, tbh);
        tb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(tbsw, tbsh);
        tb.Tag = counter.ToString();
        //Date Time Control
        int dth = duedatedb.Location.Y + (counter * 25);
        int dtsh = duedatedb.Size.Height;
        int dtsw = duedatedb.Size.Width;
        DateTimePicker dtp = new DateTimePicker();
        dtp.Location = new Point(300, dth);
        dtp.Size = new Size(dtsw, dtsh);
        dtp.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
        //Picture Box Control
        int stsh = status.Location.Y + (counter * 25);
        int stssh = status.Size.Height;
        int stssw = status.Size.Width;
        PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.Location = new Point(429, stsh);
        pb.Size = new Size(stssw, stssh);
        pb.Image = Red;
        pb.Click += new System.EventHandler(pb_Click);


        panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
        panel1.Controls.Add(dtp);
        panel1.Controls.Add(pb);
        ++counter;
    }
```

Trying to Reference the control: (For purposes of changing the image on click) [Found the Control.Find function from researching this in the MSDN Website]

```
public void pb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pb = (panel1.Controls.Find("pb",false)); 
        if (pb.Image == Red) { pb.Image = Orange; status.Tag = "Orange"; }
        else if (pb.Image == Orange) { pb.Image = green; status.Tag = "Green"; }
        else if (pb.Image == green) { pb.Image = Red; status.Tag = "Red"; }
    }
```

The essential problem here is Problem a, if you guys could see where I have gone wrong with that, I'd be able to go away and attempt to write some code to get around problem b.
(I have included Problem b in this for your suggestions on the best way to do this. -At the moment I have no clue!)

Thank you for any help received! It really is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ControlCollection.Find` looks for a control with the specified name, and you haven't set any. The variable names in your code aren't related. So, either:

```
pb.Name = "pb";
```

But that would mean you'd eventually have several items with the same name. So, seeing how you want to change the picture of the clicked PictureBox, just do this:

```
public void pb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
    if (pb.Image == Red) { pb.Image = Orange; status.Tag = "Orange"; }
    else if (pb.Image == Orange) { pb.Image = green; status.Tag = "Green"; }
    else if (pb.Image == green) { pb.Image = Red; status.Tag = "Red"; }
}
```

The `sender` argument always contains a reference to whichever control raised the event, in this case whichever picturebox was clicked!

Edit: As for your other question, I assume you'll need to do stuff to the controls later on, so I suggest you store a reference to all of them (or at least the ones you need), something like this:

```
// helper class
private class Entry
{
    public TextBox TextBox { get; private set; }
    public DateTimePicker DateTimePicker { get; private set; }
    public PictureBox PictureBox { get; private set; }

    public Entry( TextBox tb, DateTimePicker dtp, PictureBox pb )
    {
        this.TextBox = tb;
        this.DateTimePicker = dtp;
        this.PictureBox = pb;
    }
}

// member field
private List<Entry> m_Entries = new List<Entry>();

// at the end of pictureBox1_Click
public void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ....
    m_Entries.Add( new Entry( tb, dtp, pb ) );
}
```

Then you can use the items in that list to interact with your rows. You might also want to add an index, or a reference to whatever the original data structure is. Also, you might want to think about if you really should be creating the controls yourself like that or actually use some kind of table/grid control to host them!

Or perhaps just wrap up all those controls in a single `UserControl`, with logic included and all!

Comment: That's Brilliant, compiles perfectly. Thank You

Comment: @BlakeWills you got to give the man +1 and accept the answer. I was about to suggest exactly same thing

Comment: I would If I could (Don't have enough rep on this account do that!) & I'll accept the answer